# Not able to render image in circle shape in flutter application

Tags: image, flutter

I am using the below code to render the image in circle. I am using it in ExpansionTileCard widget, and it is rendering the image in square, but if I use the same code in a column in another screen it is rendering the image as circle image.

How should I make it happen to render the image as circle shaped in ExpansionTileCard?

```
CircleAvatar(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 2.0,
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
            ),
            width: 90.0,
            height: 90.0,

            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          ),
          imageUrl: widget.url,
          width: 90.0,
          height: 90.0,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
       // child: Image.network(widget.postAuthorProfilePicurl),

      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `backgroundImage` property in the `CircleAvatar`

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
    "imagelink",
  ),
),
```